# How to create shadow in JSF input field

Tags: java, javascript, css, jsf, jsf-2

I registered account into oracle.com web site and I saw something very interesting:
[image]

See the input field of the telephone number into the form. How I can reproduce the same into JSF input form? Is this made by CSS?

**CODE UPDATE**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"   
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html">
    <h:head>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            <!-- input field shadow  -->
            var placeholder = "test field"
            $("input").on({
                focus: function() {
                    if (this.value == placeholder) {
                        $(this).val("").removeClass("shadow");
                    }
                },
                blur: function() {
                    if (this.value == "") {
                        $(this).val(placeholder).addClass("shadow");
                    }
                }
            }).trigger("blur");​            
        </script>       

    </h:head>

    <h:body>
        <h1>JSF 2 textbox example with shadow</h1>

        <h:form>
            <h:inputText value="#{userBean.userName}" />
            <h:commandButton value="Submit" action="user" />
        </h:form>

    </h:body>
</html>
```

I tested this code but it's not working. Maybe I need to call the JavaScript code as function into the `<h:inputText>` tag?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is new since HTML5. It's the `placeholder` attribute, which is also known as "watermark" before the HTML5 era.

```html
<input type="text" name="phone" placeholder="e.g. +994 (12) 491 2345" />
```

This works of course only in browsers supporting HTML5. When using JSF, this works only with JSF components supporting the new HTML5 `placeholder` attribute. The standard JSF `<h:inputText>` doesn't support this natively (yet). You'd need to look for a 3rd party component library supporting this. Among them is [PrimeFaces](http://primefaces.org) with its [`<p:watermark>`](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/watermark.jsf) component:

```html
<h:inputText id="phone" value="#{register.user.phone}" />  
<p:watermark for="phone" value="e.g. +994 (12) 491 2345" />
```

This will check if HTML5 is supported and then use `placeholder`, otherwise it will bring in some JS/jQuery magic to simulate the same. Nothing of this all is done by CSS.

If using PrimeFaces is not an option for some reason, you'd need to reinvent it yourself in flavor of a custom component and/or a custom piece of JS/jQuery, exactly like `<p:watermark>` is doing under the covers.

Comment: I have a question which I'm not sure how to implement. I would like to use the example posted by @VisioN. I'm not sure how to pass this value `e.g. +994 (12) 491 2345` from JSF getter to the JavaScript code because I want to store this value into database? Is this possible?

Comment: Surely it's possible. JSF is a HTML code generator. Just let JSF print the value as if it's a JS variable.

Comment: I would like to ask you about the code posted by `@VisioN`. I inserted the code into simple JSP page but when I opened it in Firefox the shadow is not working. I suspect that I have to call the JavaScript code from the `<h:inputText>` field? But what attribute must be used to call the JavaScript code and how I must send argument to it in order to have different shadow in every input field?

Comment: Just let JSF print HTML/JS code accordingly. E.g. `<script>var foo = '#{bean.foo}';</script>` and so on. You seem to fail to understand that JSF runs on webserver and produces HTML/JS code and that HTML/JS in turn runs on webbrowser. JSF and HTML/JS doesn't run in sync or something.

Comment: Yes, now I understand your point. I thought that I can only call managed bean in html code. Never mind. I tested the code into the post but it's not working.

Comment: The browser interprets and executes HTML/JS synchronously. So your script runs before the `<input>` is ever added to the HTML DOM tree. You need to run the script when the page is finished loading.

Comment: I placed the JavaScript at the bottom of the JSF page before the `</h:body>` tag - still nothing. Lets try something else. What would you say about this `<h:inputText onmousemove="call_here_the_Javascript" value="#{userBean.userName}" />`?

Comment: It seems that you haven't loaded jQuery at all. At least, I don't see any `<script>` pointing to it in your code.

Comment: I tested the code. I get this error message `illegal character }).trigger("blur");​` Maybe there is syntax error into the JavaScript code?

Comment: There's a zero width space character ([U+200B](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/200b/index.htm)) right after your `;`. This character is usually only used in CJK or Arabic. Remove trailing spaces or retype the entire line.

Answer (score 2):

I think they are using jquery's watermark to do that way. Attached is the firebug view of that page which shows that

[image: Water Marking Text Field]

Answer (score 2):

In case if you have no possibility to use PrimeFaces, as [@BalusC stated](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10489816/1249581), you can use JavaScript/jQuery code like this:

```
var placeholder = "e.g. +358 (11) 123-45-67"
$("input").on({
    focus: function() {
        if (this.value == placeholder) {
            $(this).val("").removeClass("shadow");
        }
    },
    blur: function() {
        if (this.value == "") {
            $(this).val(placeholder).addClass("shadow");
        }
    }
}).trigger("blur");​
```

CSS class `shadow` has font `​color: #bbb`.

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/rYAbU/

Comment: Your example is very good but I see one problem here. I need to store this value - e.g. `+994 (12) 491 2345` into database table. How I can pass this value from JSF getter to JavaScript?